# Derive probability density function from moment generating function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am given this information:

$\tau$ is a constant, $\infty  >  \tau >0$

Let $X \sim G(n, \lambda)$, where $n \in \{1,2,...,\}$ ($G$ is referring to gamma distribution)

Let $Y = n \tau  + X$

Moment generating function of $Y$ (which I derived for the earlier part of the question): $M(t)_{Y} = e^{tn\tau}\left (\frac{\lambda }{\lambda -t}  \right )^{n}$

Suppose that $T_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left (\tau + Z_{i}  \right )$, where $Z_{i} \sim \varepsilon (\lambda)$

For the later part of the question, I need to find the probability density function of $T_{n}$, preferably using the MGF of $Y$

I know that $T_{n} = n\tau+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left (Z_{i}  \right )$ and $Z_{i} \sim G(1,\lambda)$, other than that, I'm lost.

How do you use the MGF of $Y$ to find the PDF of $T_{n}$? Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Clarification: $X_{i} \sim \varepsilon (\lambda)$??? Two lines below you write $X_{i} \sim G(1,\lambda)$. ??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I changed $X_{i}$ to $Z_{i}$. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: For approximate solution, look into the saddlepoint approximation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781